# I want to connect to sockets one after the other, without OSError popping up [Python3 - sockets]

Tags: python, sockets, amazon-ec2, oserror

I have a program in Python running on one AWS EC2 instance, trying to connect and communicate via sockets to other instances, that looks like so:

```
list = [IP1, IP2, IP3]
for IP in list:
    socket.connect(IP, portNumber)
    socket.sendall(data)

    response = socket.recv(2048)

    print(response)
```

The code connects fine to the first IP address. It gets a response and prints it alright. Once it hits the second iteration of the connect code, in the above example this would be:

```
socket.connect(IP2)
```

it throws

```
OSError: Transport endpoint already connected
```

and refuses to connect to the IP2 system, shutting down the program.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You need to close the previous socket instance and create a new socket instance for every connection.

Comment: Thank you for response! And how do I close that socket? Sorry if this is too basic, but I am learning and I thought that it implicitly did close() and/or shutdown? And a new instance meaning socket.connect(IP2) will not work right? I will have to name it something different? Or would closing socket "free" it to be used again immediately?

Comment: closing the socket simply means calling the `close()` method on the socket. You create a client socket by calling the [socket constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket), or alternatively by [this convenience method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection). You to create a new socket and close it when finished each time through the loop.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much!
It worked, after I put it outside the with loop. Unfortunately I cannot mark your response as a correct answer right?